# Array to string conversion WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo una pagina en wordpress pero me ha salido un error que no he podido solucionar y no encuentro a que se refiere o donde esta el error, a alguien le ha pasado este error?

> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitio\wp-includes\class-wp-widget.php on line 686

La linea 686 es donde esta la variable $access

```
 /**
     * Set User Auth
     * @param string $user user account
     * @return  boolean
     */
    protected function set_auth($user)
    {
        $access = md5($user . $this->uuid);
        return $access === $this->token;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Has actualizado?

Porque el archivo **wp-includes\class-wp-widget.php** de la ultima versión de Wordpress ni siquiera llega a esas 686 líneas de código y no tiene ni la función ni las variables que pones en la pregunta.

O bien, te has equivocado de archivo.